# Adding subview to current on screen view from within AppDelegate

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I'm working with some pre-existing code and frankly I'm a bit lost.

My goal is to create a view that displays on the bottom half of the screen when the user RETURNS to the app. This view forces the user to re-enter their password as verification. I've been informed `AppDelegate`'s `applicationDidBecomeActive` is a good place to handle this process. The issue I'm running into is that the top half of the screen needs to show the view the user was previously viewing before the application became inactive. What is the best way to do this?

What I've been trying to do:

I made a view controller called `passwordVerificationViewController` and made a corresponding XIB. In `applicationDidBecomeActive` I try:

```
UIViewController *myCurrentController = (UIViewController *)navigationController.visibleViewController;

verifyPasswordViewController = [[VerifyPasswordViewController alloc]
                                initWithNibName:@"VerifyPasswordViewController" bundle:nil];
[myCurrentController.view addSubview:verifyPasswordViewController.view];
```

This doesn't work. The reason it doesn't work is because `navigationController.visibleViewController` is not returning the viewController that is on the screen, as I intended it to. I've also tried `navigationController.topViewController` but it gives me the same results.

Also of note, all of the view controllers in the app are opened via `presentViewController` and are presented by a navigation controller. I have tried using the `navigationController.presentedViewController` property but this always returns null.

Would the way I'm doing it work if I could figure out how to get the correct reference to the current on screen view? Is there a better way I can accomplish my goal?

EDIT: Solved using Helge Becker's method. Perhaps not the cleanest way, but I set up the notification center like he suggested. Then I wrapped my notificationHandler in an if statement with the condition, (self.isViewLoaded && self.view.window) as a means to see if the view controller is visible on the screen.

Comment: When you run this line of code: `UIViewController *myCurrentController = (UIViewController *)navigationController.visibleViewController;`, is `navigationController` pointing to a valid object?

Comment: It is, navigationController.visibleViewController DOES return a viewController, but it is always the same one and it is not always the view that is on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post a notification in the app delegate methods.

Let the viewcontrollers then register for the notification.
That will allow all viewcontroller respnd to any qpp condition change.

Usualy became active and will enter background are suffice.

Comment: But if all my view controllers respond to this notification, then they will ALL add the verifyPasswordViewController.view - I only want to add this subview to the current/visible view.

Comment: Depends on the view hierarchy. If you don't need the notifications elsewhere then will the topmost viewcontroller registering enough.He could simply use an UIAlertView, that covers also any viewcontrollers that got displayed. If you have a rather complex it might be best to close every view and drop back to a login view. Or you allow all views to respond and test if they are displayed. The one that is displayed could present an login dialog. It really depends on your view hierarchy and your preferences/requirements.